# Qual è l'equivalente italiano per l'espressione francese: “veille technologique”?

Tags: translation

La domanda è già stata posta per la [lingua inglese](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102963/whats-the-english-equivalent-for-the-french-expression-veille-technologique) ed ora io mi trovo nella stessa difficoltà per una frase in italiano.

La "veglia tecnologica" è una attività costante di ricerca delle ultime novità in ambito tecnologico o scientifico, solitamente condotta in una attività commerciale col fine di assicurare ai propri clienti il miglior possibile prodotto.

Mi rendo conto in ambito lavorativo che pochi comprendono la traduzione letterale, esiste una formula equivalente in italiano?

Comment: “Spionaggio industriale”?  :-)

Comment: Ahah, beh la "veglia tecnologica" non ha una connotazione negativa, al contrario :D

Comment: La cosa più sensata che mi viene in mente è "aggiornamento tecnologico". Non trasmette esattamente lo stesso messaggio però, me ne rendo conto, il ruolo sembra più passivo che attivo. Probabilmente in vari contesti è anche accettabile usare il termine inglese (probabilmente fa anche molto di più l'effetto buzzword, ammesso che questo sia desiderabile).

Comment: Io manterrei il termine inglese "technology watch". La lingua italiana è piena di termini inglesi nell'ambito delle nuove tecnologie,  uno in più non penso sia un problema. http://www.opti.org/en/vigilancia_tec.asp

Comment: Suppongo che il termine inglese non stupirebbe nessuno, almeno al lavoro, ma verrebbe capito? Temo di no, perché non è di uso comune.

Comment: Non penso capirebbero nemmeno una improbabile traduzione in italiano (controllo tecnologico, veglia tecnologica?). Una volta spiegato verrebbe capito come abbiamo capito cos'è un App, un download, un software o una start-up.

Comment: È una osservazione ragionevole, upvoted

Comment: Si potrebbe usare il termine maratona al posto di veglia dato che viene usata in molti ambiti, soprattutto televisivo.

Comment: @AndreaTosoni _maratona_ non è adatto, perché indica un evento, non una funzione. In ambito istituzionale invece si usa _osservatorio_ (che a me non piace, ma questo è un altro paio di maniche)

Comment: @WalterTross Io infatti l'avevo capito come un evento e non come una funzione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non sapevo che esistesse questo termine!

Ho trovato [Sorveglianza tecnologica](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:C:2001:240E:0120:0123:IT:PDF) o [Monitoraggio Tecnologico](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2011:0822:FIN:IT:PDF) (fai una ricerca per parola per trovarla nel testo). Nei testi corrispondenti in inglese si usa proprio *Tecnology watch*.

Tuttavia, non penso che nessuno di questi tre termini sia noto al grande pubblico, come discusso nei commenti. Sarebbe più comprensibile con una perifrasi/spiegazione:

> Il capo mi ha incaricato di informarmi sulle ultime tecnologie disponibili

In termini più ampi, fai un lavoro simile quando prepari un *benchmark*, anche se sostituire un'espressione straniera con un'altra non aiuta molto.